# CridControl: программно выставить IsChecked во всех rows

Tags: c#, devexpress

Есть:

XAML:

```
<dxg:GridControl x:Name="GridControl_AllPC" Margin="0" Height="370" Width="245">
<dxg:GridControl.Columns>
<dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Выбор" Width="50"HorizontalHeaderContentAlignment="Center"  Binding="{Binding Выбор, Mode=TwoWay}" VisibleIndex="0">
</dxg:GridColumn>
<dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Бот" Width="140" HorizontalHeaderContentAlignment="Center" Binding="{Binding Бот, Mode=OneWay}"  VisibleIndex="1"/>
</dxg:GridControl.Columns>
```

Привязанная коллекция:

```
public static ObservableCollection<DataGridSource> PcCollection = new ObservableCollection<DataGridSource>();

    public class DataGridSource
        {
        // Хандлер
        private event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        // Выбор
        private bool _DG_CheckBox;
        public bool Выбор
        {
            get
            {
                return this._DG_CheckBox;
            }
            set
            {
                this._DG_CheckBox = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        // Бот 
        private string _DG_Bot;
        public string Бот
        {
            get
            {
                return this._DG_Bot;
            }
            set
            {
                this._DG_Bot = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        // Реализация INotifyPropertyChanged
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        // Переопределяем Equals для объекта
        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            // Если объект NULL возвращаем false
            if (obj == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            // Если параметр не может быть приведен к данному типу возвращаем false
            DataGridSource s = obj as DataGridSource;
            if ((object)s == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            // Возвращет true если поля совпадают
            return (Бот == s.Бот);
        }

        // Переопределяем Equals для тип
        public bool Equals(DataGridSource s)
        {
            // Если объект NULL возвращаем false
            if ((object)s == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return (Бот == s.Бот);
        }

        // Переназначаем GetHashCode
        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return Бот.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

Есть кнопка "Выбрать все\снять выбор", в задачу которой входит выставить все чекбоксы в колонке "Выбор" в true\false. Делаю-то через коллекцию так:

```
if (!Bot_IsSelectAll)
            {
                Bot_IsSelectAll = true;

                foreach (var item in PcCollection)
                {
                    if (!item.Выбор)
                    {
                        item.Выбор = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Bot_IsSelectAll = false;

                foreach (var item in PcCollection)
                {
                    if (item.Выбор)
                    {
                        item.Выбор = false;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Но, к сожалению, данный вариант не срабатывает. В чем может заключаться проблема?

Comment: Никогда не имел дела с devexpress, но код

    FieldName="Бот" Binding="{Binding Бот, Mode=OneWay}"

кажется мне подозрительным. Зачем говорить два раза одно и то же по сути?

Comment: Да, а что означает «не срабатывает»? Крэш, зависание? Ваша функция не вызывается? Она вызывается, но получает на вход не те данные, которые вы ожидаете? Данные те, но функция идёт не по той ветке, на которую вы рассчитывали? Функция пробегает, но объекты не обновляются? Объекты обновляются, но визуальное состояние контролов не меняется?

Comment: 1) Если не указать FieldName="Бот" - колонка будет иметь другое название.
2) Объекты обновляются, но визуальное состояние контролов не меняется.

Comment: Если не указать жестко филд нейм: http://i6.5cm.ru/i/Mw5S.png

Comment: @z668: А если убрать тогда Binding? И/или не использовать просто `Name`?

Comment: @VladD, не помогает. Наткнулся случайно на тему на стеке: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17815883/checkbox-is-not-checked-in-devexpress-gridcontrol-using-wpf

Пробовал и таким образом, тоже бесполезно. Объекты обновляются, но визуальное состояние контролов не меняется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хм. Мне кажется, вы неправильно оповещаете об изменениях.

Попробуйте так:

```
public class DataGridSource : INotifyPropertyChanged // добавили интерфейс
{
    // превращаем private в public
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

Поскольку event был private, его никто не видел, соответственно и подписаться на него никто не мог. Да и никто о нём не знал, т. к. не был заявлен интерфейс `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: @VladD, благодарю. В точку. Причем недостаточно дать public видимость, нужно еще и наследоваться от : INotifyPropertyChanged как Вы и написали. Огромное спасибо за помощь, выручили уже не в первый раз.

Comment: @z668: Рад, что смог помочь. Хорошо, что вы выложили код, без него я думал в неправильную сторону.